# Authentication of Angular App via IdentityServer4 is failing when UI and AUTH solutions are hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: .net, angular, azure, identityserver4

---

There is an UI application built on angular framework and currently hosted in Remote IIS server.

This UI application is configured to use IdentityServer4 for authentication.
And this AUTH related solution too is hosted in the same remote IIS server as that of UI application.

Both of them are currently working as expected when hosted in one Remote IIS server.

---

And currently, these solutions ( both UI and AUTH ) are migrated to AZURE APP SERVICES.

But after this, Authentication\Redirection is failing with the error as given below:
"Invalid Login Request : There are no login schemes configured for this client".

It's been confirmed that the "Redirect URLs" are updated to the latest cloud domain application end points both at the client solution end and at the Auth solution end.

And 'Client ID', 'Client Name' and 'Client Secrete' parameter values are unchanged and are matching at both the ends.

'Grant Type' used w.r.t the client at AUTH end is 'Implicit'.

It would be of great favor if someone could provide some ideas on the possible root cause of this issue.

---